# Есть ли способ передать значение из QString в QGraphicsTextItem?

Tags: c++, qt

Делаю график в Qt.Нужно подписать координатные оси. Делаю это в цикле c помощью `QGraphicsTextItem`, так как обычное `QGraphicsScene->addText ()` не позволяет задать координаты надписей.

Нашел в Интернете пример объявления такого `QGraphicsTextItem`:

```
QGraphicsTextItem *textItem = new QGraphicsTextItem("I'm text.", 0, 0);
textItem->setPos(67, 90); 
scene->addItem(textItem);
```

Но мне нужно передать в `QGraphicsTextItem` не просто строку в кавычках, а значение `QString str`. И вот тут-то мне  и выдает ошибку

> no matching function for call to
>   'QGraphicsTextItem::QGraphicsTextItem(QString*&, int, int)'

Пробовал передавать так:

```
  OXText = new QGraphicsTextItem (str, 0,0);
```

Я так понимаю, что такого вызова нет в конструкторе `QGraphicsTextItem`, поэтому компилятор и ругается, но может есть способ для того, чтобы передать в `QGraphicsTextItem` готовую надпись из `str`?

Полный фрагмент кода.

В заголовочном файле

```
  double xmin;
  double dx;
  double xmax;   
  QGraphicsTextItem *OXText;
```

В файле .cpp

```
xmin = 0.0;
xmax = 2.0;
dx = 0.05;

QString *str =new QString;


for (int i =1; i<10;i++){

    double OX = (xmin + i*dx)/10;
    str->number(OX);
    OXText = new QGraphicsTextItem (str, 0,0);
    OXText->setPos(100*i,100*i);
    graphicsScene->addItem(OXText);
    }
```

Обновление: сделал из `QString * str` просто `QString str`. Ошибок не выдает, но и надпись почему-то не выводит.

Мой обновленный код

```
xmin = 0.0;
xmax = 2.0;
dx = 0.05;

QString str ="";


for (int i =1; i<10;i++){

    double OX = (xmin + i*dx)/10;
    str.number(OX);
    OXText = new QGraphicsTextItem (str, 0,0);
    OXText->setPos(50*i,graphicsScene->height()-50);
    graphicsScene->addItem(OXText);
```

Comment: "так как обычное QGraphicsScene->addText () не позволяет задать координаты надписей" фигня, позволяет. `addText` вернет вам указатель на объект, запоминайте его в переменную и устанавливайте координаты

Comment: "Ошибок не выдает, но и надпись почему-то не выводит." так вы пустую строку пытаетесь вывести, по крайней мере по приведенному коду. У вас пустая строка и появляется :)

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Я в строку str хочу передать число из OX и по идее делаю это с помощью строки str.number(OX); или я не прав?

Comment: ваш код в цикле можно заменить на `graphicsScene->addText(QString::number(xmin + i*dx)/10)->setPos(...)`. Если не сработает, проверяйте на предмет правильности координат, например выводя прямоугольники вместо надписей по тем же координатам.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение. Вместо `str.number (OX);` Нужно написать `str.setNum(OX)` В итоге код подписи оси:

```
xmin = 0.0;
xmax = 2.0;
dx = 0.05;

for (int i =1; i<10;i++){

    double OX = (xmin + i*dx)/10;
    QString str;
    str.setNum(OX);
    OXText = new QGraphicsTextItem (str, 0,0);
    OXText->setPos(50*i,graphicsScene->height()-50);
    graphicsScene->addItem(OXText);
    }
```

Еще одно решение, спасибо @BeardedBeaver за решение в одну строку кода в цикле

```
xmin = 0.0-dx;
xmax = 2.0;
dx = 0.5;

for (int i =1; i<10;i++){
    graphicsScene->addText(QString::number((xmin + i*dx)/10))->setPos(...);
}
```

Comment: тело цикла можно сократить до одной строки, смотрите мой комментарий под вопросом

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Выдает ошибку  no match for 'operator/' in 'QString::number(double, char, int)(103, 6) / 10'

Comment: Со скобками промазал чуток, неудобно набирать в редакторе комментариев. Вот так вроде правильно `graphicsScene->addText(QString::number((xmin + i*dx)/10))->setPos`

Comment: @BeardedBeaver Да, так работает, спасибо.